# Set an android phone as hotspot, how to get the urls issued by WIFI clients?

Tags: android, caching, android-wifi

I want to write a http cache application on android phones, its functionality is:

1. Set the android as a WIFI hotspot
2. Laptops can connect it
3. On laptops, we can visit some websites
4. My application on android can found the urls issued by clients
5. My application can give a quick response from cache if the url matches some rules

But I don't know is there any way to find the urls issued by clients and give responses to them, is it possible?